# how can I make this code work?

Tags: javascript, object

I have the code below but I cannot call nextPromo because it is not a function. How can I make this work? I am trying to setup a rotator using object oriented style. I am new to it so i am very confused. I have tried many things but I jsut don't know and I am very frustrated with it, please help

```
function promoSlides(s){
    this.index = 0;
    this.prevIndex = 0;
    this.currentVeh = "";
    this.t;
    this.slides = s;
    this.len = this.slides.length;
    this.sortWeight = function(){
        ($('body').hasClass('en')) ? this.slides.sort(SortByWeight) : this.slides.sort(SortByWeightFr);
    };

    function SortByWeight(a,b) { return b.weight - a.weight; }
    function SortByWeightFr(a,b) { return a.frWeight - b.frWeight; }

    this.startTimer = function(){ this.t = setTimeout("this.nextPromo()", 3000); }

    this.nextPromo = function(){
       if(this.index > 0 || this.prevIndex > 0) $(this.slides[this.prevIndex].el).css("display","none");
       $(this.slides[this.index].el).css("display","block");
       this.prevIndex = this.index;
       this.index = (this.index < this.len-1) ? this.index+1 : 0;
       this.startTimer();
    }

    return true;
} ;
```

Comment: You used a tirnary operator for no real reason. Quotes in your settimeout is an eval rather than function call.

Comment: I remove the quotes and it gives this error says too much recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Here is a simplified example which I have tested. This uses setInterval to periodically advance the slide index. The "next" functionality is contained within an anonymous function.

```
function promoSlides(s) {

    this.startTimer = function () {

        setInterval(
        function () {
            alert("called");

            //                if (this.index > 0 || this.prevIndex > 0) {
            //                    $(this.slides[this.prevIndex].el).css("display", "none");
            //                }

            //                $(this.slides[this.index].el).css("display", "block");
            //                this.prevIndex = this.index;
            //                this.index = (this.index < this.len - 1) ? this.index + 1 : 0;
        }, 3000


        );
    }

    return true;
};

var p = new promoSlides(null);
p.startTimer();
```

Comment: ok this calls the function but i get too much recursion issue, i don't understand how it happens it should just keep rotating

Comment: this does work, I put in that nextPromo is because i will eventually have a stop to pause the slides but when i want to resume i want it to wait 3 seconds before resuming. I should be able to build off of this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `nextPromo` is a function. You can call it like:

```
this.nextPromo();
```

Or, if that doesn't work, you can just call it like a normal function:

```
nextPromo();
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NathanJohnson/bcnHw/) for an example of this kind of function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I took the quotes out but i get this error says too much recursion, maybe i am setting the time events wrong, how can i fix it i dont get it

Comment: @user930795 I think that taking the quotes out messed it up. What was the error before you took out the quotes? _Edit: Nevermind, I just saw that someone else answered._

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a function to `this.nextPromo`, so calling `this.nextPromo();` should work.